# Копировать файлы с помощью PowerShell или bat

Tags: bat, powershell

У меня есть папка с файлами, и я хотел бы сделать копии этих файлов с названиями, отличающимися от исходных на 1 символ. Например, для файла с именем abcd.txt создать его копию abc.txt (имя исходного файла минус последний символ). И так для всех файлов в папке.
Например если в папке были такие файлы:

```
abcd.txt
foo.txt
bar.txt
```

То после применения скрпита должны быть такие:

```
abcd.txt
abc.txt
foo.txt
fo.txt
bar.txt
ba.txt
```

Понимаю, что это можно сделать с помощью PowerShell или bat, но не хватает навыков для этого. Буду признателен за помощь

Comment: А если урезанное на символ имя - уже присутствует? А если имя - из одного символа?

Comment: @Akina этот скрипт нужен для строго определённого набора файлов, в котором таких проблем быть не может

Comment: Задача - одноразовая? или регулярная?

Comment: @Akina в целом да, одноразовая. Просто фалов много, и вручную делать это не хотелось бы

Comment: `DIR /B > list.txt`. Загрузить в Excel. Поделить на имя и расширение. Составить команду переименования одного файла функциями листа. Сохранить полученное в текстовый файл. Переименовать в батник. Запустить. Дел на две минуты.

Comment: @Akina звучит логично. Спасибо за идею!

Comment: Если задача разовая, то лучше воспользоваться файловым менеджером. Например, в TotalCommander есть групповое переименование с кучей возможностей.

Answer (score 0):

mv кого и куда

```
mv text.txt ../
```

Comment: @Akina, прочти внимательно вопрос! POWERSHELL. В ней есть команда MV!

Comment: Ok, в этот моменте уговорил. Но как это знание поможет автору решить задачу - я не понимаю. Проблема у него не в том, какую команду применить (кстати, ему надо копировать, а `mv` перемещает/переименует), а в обрезке последнего символа.